# What is the biblical basis for modern-day prophets?

Tags: prophecy

I've been seeing people lately who have claimed to be recipients of divine revelation from God (if not in that exact language) and that we all need to heed their warnings or -insert consequence here-. They say that essentially, God didn't cover everything that would ever happen in the bible, so he uses people to communicate his will to people today. Is there biblical basis for this being true? If so, how can we verify that it is from God?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good question. For the second question please see [What was the Biblical basis for testing the truthfulness of every statement made by 'real' Prophets or Apostles?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14632) and [How does one discern between thoughts inspired by the Holy Spirit and those produced from themselves](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16222)

Comment: How to identify false prophets has been asked a couple of times already.  Here's [one example](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/how-do-we-identify-false-prophets), which was marked as a duplicate of yet another.

Comment: @David Thanks! This is my first time using this website, and I'm still not quite sure how it works. If I have a question derived from the answer to the other question, should I comment on the answer, edit this question, or post a new question?

Comment: cf. [Acts 2:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+2%3A17&version=RSVCE); [1 Pet 2:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Peter+2%3A9&version=RSVCE) fulfilling Moses' wish: [Num 11:29](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+11%3A29&version=RSVCE).

Comment: @FMS. I am not sure that Numbers talk about predicting the future - more ecstatically praising God etc. The question (I think) is about Biblical support for predicting the future where the Bible falls short. A good question. +1.

Comment: @Flimzy I see this as more of a Biblical basis that there are or can still be prophets today. It's a level higher than the question you've marked as duplicate. That question assumes prophesy still exists today. This question challenges that assumption.

Comment: @gideonmarx The New People of God is the Church.

Comment: @Zenon Please see also [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31056/what-is-the-catholic-churchs-view-of-anne-catherine-emmerich-can-her-visions) and [the selected answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31056/what-is-the-catholic-churchs-view-of-anne-catherine-emmerich-can-her-visions/31137#31137).

Comment: @fredsbend: But the answer to that question implies the answer to this one.

Comment: It may not be a complete duplicate, but once look at the other questions which have been asked before the OP will be more able to ask a new one which is clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, thanks FMS & curious. Shem's answer solved my question, so I'm all set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scriptures below show that God speaks through prophets, and that he will always speak through prophets.

> ### God Speaks Through Prophets
>
> "... Believe in the Lord your God, so shall ye be established;
>   **believe his prophets**, so shall ye prosper." [(2 Chronicles 20:20)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/20.20?lang=eng#19)
>
> "Surely the Lord God *will do nothing*, but **he revealeth his secret unto
>   his servants the prophets**." [(Amos 3:7)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/amos/3.7?lang=eng#6)
>
> "Now therefore ye are no more strangers and foreigners, but
>   fellowcitizens with the saints, and of the household of God; And are
>   **built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets**, Jesus Christ
>   himself being the chief corner stone;" [(Ephesians 2:19-20;)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/2.19-20?lang=eng#18)
>
> "And God hath set some in the church, first apostles, secondarily **prophets**, thirdly teachers, after that miracles, then gifts of healings, helps, governments, diversities of tongues." [(1 Corinthians 12:28)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/1-cor/12.28?lang=eng#27)
>
> ### Eternal Nature of God
>
> "Jesus Christ **the same yesterday, and to day, and *for ever*.**"
>   [(Hebrews 13:8)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/heb/13.8?lang=eng#7)
>
> "For I am the Lord, **I change not**; ..." [(Malachi 3:6;)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/mal/3.6?lang=eng#5)

Scripture is the written words of the Prophets, the Bible is the word of God spoken through prophets. God calls prophets to deliver his words to the children of men, but it is important to understand that a man can only be a prophet if he is called of God:

> "Ye have not chosen me, but **I have chosen you**, and ordained you, that
>   ye should go ***and bring forth fruit***..." [(John 15:16)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/john/15.16?lang=eng#15)

## How to verify a prophet of God

It is wise to be wary of any man that claims to have received revelation from God, especially when he claims to have received it on behalf of someone else.

> ¶**Beware of false prophets**, which come to you in sheep’s clothing,
>   but inwardly they are ravening wolves.  [(Matt 7:15;)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/2-chr/20.20?lang=eng#19)

Just as Christ told his disciples to go and bring forth fruit, he also promised that we can tell a man is a disciple of God *by their fruits*.

> 16 **Ye shall know them by their fruits.** Do men gather grapes of thorns,
>   or figs of thistles?
>
> 17 Even so every good tree bringeth forth good fruit; but a corrupt
>   tree bringeth forth evil fruit.
>
> 18 A good tree cannot bring forth evil fruit, neither can a corrupt
>   tree bring forth good fruit.
>
> 19 Every tree that bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down, and
>   cast into the fire.
>
> 20 Wherefore by **their fruits ye shall know them.** [(Matt 7:16-20;)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/amos/3.7?lang=eng#6)

How shall we know them by their fruits?

> "But when the Comforter is come, whom I will send unto you from the
>   Father, even **the Spirit of truth**, which proceedeth from the Father, he
>   shall testify of me." [(John 15:26)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/john/15.26?lang=eng#20)

In Galatians chapter 5, Paul explains that a true disciple of Christ is led by the Spirit, and lists the *fruits* of the spirit.

> 22 But **the fruit of the Spirit** is love, joy, peace, longsuffering,
>   gentleness, goodness, faith,
>
> 23 Meekness, temperance: against such there is no law. [(Gal 5:22;)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/2.19-20?lang=eng#18)

To know truth you must pray unto the Lord always, so that he may confirm or deny the words of any supposed prophet. If a man claims to have received a prophecy from God, and you can feel the spirit while you hear his words, then take the matter to prayer. The Spirit will confirm or deny the truthfulness of all things. If a man speaks words that cause fear and doubt, pray to know if he is a false prophet, and again the Spirit will speak the truth. Anyone that preaches fear and doubt is a false prophet.

Comment: This is answered from an LDS perspective, which believes that living prophets are the foundation of Christ's church, see ["What Is a Living Prophet?"](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1973/07/what-is-a-living-prophet?lang=eng) for more.

Comment: Interestingly you left out a few verses, like Hebrews 1:1-2  God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past unto the fathers by the prophets,

2 Hath in these last days spoken unto us by his Son, whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds;